# What is a scale consisting of Root, m3, M3, P4, P5, M6, m7 called?

Tags: theory, scales

In a chord progression that follows a circle-of-fourths pattern with each chord being a dominant 7 chord (each chord is R, M3, 5, m7), each successive pair of chords contains 7 notes, with one shared note (that note being the root of the first chord and the 5 of the second chord). If you treat that shared note as the root of a scale, the interval pattern of that scale is R-m3-M3-4-5-6-m7 (or: W+H,H,H,W,W,H,W). Is there a name for a scale with that interval pattern?

Comment: That looks an awful lot like a blues scale if you decide to make the m7 the root, i.e. it's a blues scale on the second mode (in the same way as dorian is the "second mode" of ionian)

Comment: @user121330 If you started on the m7 you'd be missing both thirds.

Comment: Are you sure that's a minor third and not an augmented second? Two thirds and no second doesn't look very neat.

Comment: ...and if you allow A2, probably the simplest way to communicate the scale in the Western world would be "mixolydian #2".

Answer (score 1):

Researcher Ian Ring has categorised a huge number of scales. On his page ["A Study of Scales"](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/) he names this scale as 'Mela Vagadhisvari'.

Comment: This article on Wikipedia offers some background on the scale and compositions using it: [Vagadheeswari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagadheeswari).